# how to convert nested list which contain key - value pair to json format using python

Tags: python, json

I have ['key','value'] format list, which also contain sub-list. How can I convert nested list to JSON format in python

```
[[' key ', ' 1542633482511430199'
 ],
 ['value=>>>BasicData',
  [['isConfirmAndOrder', '0'],['brmRequestId', 'BR-2018-0000124'],
  ['requestType','batch'],['projectId', 'PRJ-2018-0000477'],
  ['createdOn', 'Mon Nov 19 18:48:02 IST 2018']]
 ],    
 ['createdBy=>>>BasicData',
  [['userId', '999996279'],    ['email', 'ITEST275@ITS.JNJ.com'],
  ['firstName', 'Iris'],    ['lastName', 'TEST275'],
  ['ntId', 'itest275'],    ['region', 'NA'],
  [' LastAccessTime ', ' 1542639905785 ']]
 ]
]
```

Excepted format is

```
{
"key": "1542633482511430199",
"value=>>>BasicData": {
    "isConfirmAndOrder": "0",
    "brmRequestId": "BR-2018-0000124"
        .
},
"createdBy=>>>BasicData": {
    "userId": "999996279",
    "email": "ITEST275@ITS.JNJ.com"
        .
 }
        .
 }
```

Actually format of large data is:

```
[
 [
  ['key11','value11']
  ['key12',['key13','value13']]
  ['key14',['key15','value15']]
 ]
[
  ['key21','value21']
  ['key22',['key23','value23']]
  ['key24',['key25','value25']]
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple recursive function for this:

```
def to_dict_recursive(x):
    d = {}
    for key, value in x:
        if isinstance(value, list):
            value = to_dict_recursive(value)
        else:
            value = value.strip()  # get rid of unnecessary whitespace
        d[key.strip()] = value
    return d

to_dict_recursive(x)
# {'createdBy=>>>BasicData': {'displayName': 'Iris TEST275',
#   'email': 'ITEST275@ITS.JNJ.com',
#   'firstName': 'Iris',
#   'lastName': 'TEST275',
#   'ntId': 'itest275',
#   'region': 'NA',
#   'roles': '[0]CG510_DHF_AP_Role',
#   'userId': '999996279'},
#  'formulaDetails=>>>BasicData': {'CreationTime': '1542633482512',
#   'LastAccessTime': '1542639905785',
#   'batchSizeUnits': 'kg<<<<<<',
#   'hitCount': '1',
#   'version': '1'},
#  'key': '1542633482511430199',
#  'value=>>>BasicData': {'brmRequestId': 'BR-2018-0000124',
#   'createdMonth': 'Nov',
#   'createdOn': 'Mon Nov 19 18:48:02 IST 2018',
#   'department': 'Global Packaging',
#   'gxp': '1',
#   'id': '1542633482511430199',
#   'isConfirmAndOrder': '0',
#   'isFilling': 'false',
#   'projectId': 'PRJ-2018-0000477',
#   'projectName': 'Automation_Product_By_Admin',
#   'requestType': 'batch',
#   'status': 'New',
#   'statusDescription': 'Batch request created',
#   'updatedOn': 'Mon Nov 19 18:48:02 IST 2018'}}
```

(I ran this in Python 3.6 so the order of the keys in the dictionary representation is different than insertion order. In Python 3.7+ this would be different.)

You can even make this into a dict comprehension:

```
def to_dict_recursive(x):
    return {key.strip(): to_dict_recursive(value) if isinstance(value, list)
                         else value.strip
            for key, value in x}
```

---

Since apparently some elements in your object are not a two-element list of key and value, you can add a simple guard against that:

```
def to_dict_recursive(x):
    d = {}
    try:
        for key, value in x:
            if isinstance(value, list):
                value = to_dict_recursive(value)
            else:
                value = value.strip()
            d[key.strip()] = value
    except ValueError:
        return x
    return d

x = [[' key ', ' 1542633482511430199'],
 ["test", ["a", "b", "c"]]
]
to_dict_recursive(x)
# {'key': '1542633482511430199', 'test': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Comment: Thanks Graipher, But When I this code on large data, it through  a error is : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)   = =  for function to_dict_recursive(x).

Comment: @mahesh That means some entries are different than in your example. There seem to be entries where you have more than a key and a value, maybe sometimes you have a plain list as the value, instead of a list representing a dictionary? Just `try` and `except` for that error to find out. Will see if I can come up with a fix for that.

Comment: @mahesh: Simply added that iterables not of length 2 will be kept as is.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if `mylist` is a key-value pair list, then `dict(mylist)` simply returns a dictionary version of it.  The tricky part is traversing deep into those nested lists to replace them with dictionaries.  Here's a recursive function that does that:

```
# Where <kv> is your giant list-of-lists.
def kv_to_dict(kv):
    if isinstance(kv, list):
        kv = dict(kv)
    for k in kv:
        if isinstance(kv[k], list):
            kv[k] = kv_to_dict(kv[k])
    return kv

newdict = kv_to_dict(kvpairs)
```

Once you have things converted to a dictionary, you can just use `json.dumps()` to format it as JSON:

```
import json
as_json = json.dumps(newdict, indent=4)
print(as_json)
```

I see though that you've tried something similar and got an error.  Are you sure that all of the lists in your data are really key-value pairs, and not for example a list of 3 strings?